# Interpolating values using a fitted function

Tags: matlab, curves, extrapolation

I have data for $x,y$ where $y=[0,0,0.016,0.65,0.97,0.99,1]$ and $x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]$. For this data I fitted a sigmoid type function as $f(x)=a/(1+exp(-b*x)+c)$. I fitted this using matlab cftool, and the obtained parameter values are:

```
a =   1.748e-07  (-5.743e-07, 9.238e-07)
b =  4.047  (2.914, 5.18)
c = -1  (-1, -1)
```

[image]

But the issue is, say I try to interpolate values at $x=5$ using the above estimated values, then for $x=5$, $f(x)=230$ but $f(x)$ should result in values between 0 and 1.
Is this an issue in the used function form for $f(x)$? Or is it because estimated value of $a$ has a large confidence interval?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If $c=-1$ then $f(x)=ae^{bx}$ which is not the graph displayed. Parameter $c$ is in the wrong place. The equation should be $f(x)=a/(1+e^{-b(x-x_0)})=a/(1+ce^{-bx})$.

Comment: @sammygerbil thank you